# Why was Carpathia overloaded?

Tags: titanic

If Carpathia was not full when she rescued Titanic survivors, why was she so overloaded?  There should have been plenty of room and spare cabins.

Comment: What research have you done? Where have you looked?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean **under**loaded?

Comment: At least one [article](https://www.encyclopedia-titanica.org/out-of-the-dark-of-the-dawn-rms-carpathia-craig-stringer.html) agrees with the OP, *The Carpathia was now overcrowded, with space and supplies at a premium.*.  The Carpathia seems to have had 743 passengers, and took on over 700, so I could see supplies being an issue, but unless they only carry enough beds to accommodate the expected passengers, space being an issue does seem confusing...

Comment: Space can't have been a problem as steerage could hold over 2,000, but Carpathia only had room for 100 1st class and 200 2nd class. Apparently, the Carpathia captain gave up his own quarters to 3 wives of millionaires so I guess you can't put millionaires wives in steerage...

Comment: @T.E.D.: When Carpathia left the scene, there were no survivors left in the water; they had picked up every survivor they could find. So there was no "underload". I am quite sure they would have picked up, and made room for, many more if there *were* any more. "Overcrowded" is a relative term here; I feel it refers to relative comfort, not maximum capacity of the ship when you abandon all thoughts of comfort and go for as many souls as you could transport.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, Carpathia had a lot of spare space. The problem was, most of that space was steerage.

After a refit in 1905, Carpathia could carry 2450 people, [according to the statement given by captain Ronson to the US Senate Inquiry commission](https://www.titanicinquiry.org/USInq/AmInq01Rostron03.php), 250 in first and second class combined, and 2200 in third class dormitories. The captain might've been off, though - he states several times that he does not know the exact capacity of his ship (it seems weird to me, but I'm not that well versed in ship operation; also the captain might've tried to dodge questions related to the problem of ships of that time having rescue equipment vastly inadequate to the number of passengers carried). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Carpathia) lists a bit different numbers, although with no source provided: 100 first-class, 200 second-class, 2250 third-class for total capacity of 2550. Thus, if we go by sheer capacity - even with lower capacity cited by the captain, Carpathia could've taken in another thousand passengers.

I couldn't find the exact number of first and second class passengers onboard the Carpathia during the Titanic disaster. Data given [here](https://www.encyclopedia-titanica.org/carpathia-passenger-list.html) lists ~130 first class passengers (which does not agree with wiki 100 first-class passengers, but still - the first class wasn't empty). Carpatia rescued 201 1st class passengers, 118 2nd class passengers from Titanic. Carpathia's crew might've been reluctant to put first and second class passengers in steerage - and that would lead to ovecrowding in those classes.